# Change background slider revolution with particles.js plugin

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, particles, revolution-slider

I am using slider revolution with particles.js in WordPress site. I am using white background color and black circle colors.

I want to change the white background color to black and black circle colors to white. When I do that, the black background color becomes transparent and the image becomes visible, and the white color inside circles becomes not transparent.

You can see a GIF illustartion [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2wpn.jpg):

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can learn more about [ask] a question to better support the folks who can help you with your question.  Thanks!

Comment: Checkout here: https://particles.matteobruni.it/#background Particles.js doesn’t support that configuration